# How to drag and drop files from my application to the Finder

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, drag-and-drop

If I want to drag a text label starting on mouse down event to the Finder in plain c++ (I can mix it with objective c), how can this be done?

I have tried this code when mixing c++ and objective c but my text labels are not objective c objects just c++ or what they should be called:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/patterns/gggg.mid" isDirectory:NO];
; // Assume this exists
NSPasteboard *pboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard];
[pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLPboardType] owner:nil];
[fileURL writeToPasteboard:pboard];
```

When I try this code on the text labels mouseDown nothing happens. The mouse down event function is working but no drag and drop.

How can I make a proper drag and drop from a text label that isn't objective c?
Every sample that I can find are all for objective c objects..

**EDIT**
The text label (CTextLabel) is from the VST GUI 4.0 and it's not subclass of a NSView.

Comment: What do you mean "a text label that isn't Objective-C"? Are you using Carbon? You write of the text label's `mouseDown`. In what class is that method defined if not (a subclass of) an `NSView`?

Comment: @KenThomases the text label (CTextLabel) is from the VST GUI 4.0 and it's not subclass of a NSView.